# What is the advantage of providing a Tokenized Authentication in an application with Spring Boot Backend over SecurityContextHolder?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization, jwt

I was getting started with Spring Boot and Angular 7 and I came across user authentication.

Let's assume the following: I have a frontend with Angular 7 and a Backend with Spring Boot that offers API's that can be accessed via HTTP.

So I know that usually the frontend authenticates the user with e.g. `JWT` that stores all necessary information about the user that might be needed. But I came across the `SecurityContextHoler` of Spring Boot Security:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

This allows me to simply access granted Authorities and so on. So I thought about the following:

Using JWT for the frontend grants the following advantages (as far as I know): 
* Users can identify when using API's
* Users may be prevented from certain UI-Elements (based on roles stored in JWT)
* Modification prevention due to checksum (invalid token afterwards)

Now I could also add a check in my Controller in the Backend that checks the `SecurityContextHolder` for user permission (something like a Service that checks the current context permissions vs the needed permission and returns true/false). Wouldn't that be even more save, since it is in the backend (so in my inmagination everything that runs server-sided is always a little more save than what runs client-sided)?

I can store information in the frontend (like roles and a username) to use them for the UI-based-access prevention to still have the same advantages as JWT provides, but I do not have the "effort" of implementing the JWT creation.

But obviously it is not common to do it that way (at least I never saw it), so what is the advantage of the Tokenization?

Answer (score 1):

They are not mutually exclusive. You would use what you call "Tokenized Authentication", like an oAuth2 Bearer token most likely in a JWT when the Authentication is performed by a separate system from your Spring Boot backend. For example, you may be using Okta, Keycloak, Google or Facebook to authenticate the user.

At a minimum, your Spring Boot backend stores the username extracted from the JWT in the `Authentication`. You can get Spring Boot to extract any roles in the token and add those to `Authentication::grantedAuthorites`. If your backend system, has it's own set of roles in addition to what's in the token, then the backend could implement a `PrincipalExtractor` to load a UserDetails object for this user from the database as the `Principal` and merge the roles in the token with those store in the local database.

You'll probably want to security certain methods in your backend with method security annotations like `@PreAuthorize()`, since you shouldn't trust the front end. The method security will check permissions, like `hasRole("ADMIN")` or `hasPermission(object, 'READ')` using the `Principal` object in `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`

In the end, the token assures the backend the user accessing it is who they say they are, i.e. Authentication, but does not necessarily tell the backend what they are Authorized to do. Yes, if you control the Authentication server you can include roles in the JWT, but roles don't usually provide as fine a grained control as is required.

Independent of what level of security you implement, the token is translated into an Authorization so you can use the Spring Security framework to manage access within your backend code.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 type of token in spring security OAuth2: 
 1. InMemory token Store
 2.JWT token store 
 3.JDBC token store

So now you’re talking the JWT token store. The most powerful of JWT token store is prevent the authorization server load against to the database for checking such as role,token expired so it is related database load performance. Since all the information such as: role,username, token expire ,etc include in token itself. So the authorization server or other resource sever may using the public key to verify this token itself without invoke to data store.

Hope helpful! ☺️